# Why does same code in C++ and Python generate different outputs?

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I have the TaxiCab number program implemented in both Python and C++, I dont understand why same code gives different out put, can someone enlighten me on the workings of these loops.

Check the output of the codes, both language skipped certain pairs of answers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include "iomanip"

using namespace std;

int ramanujan(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int x;
  int y;
  std::cout << "Inside Ramanujan Function and out\n";
  std::cout << setw(10) << "a" << setw(10) << "b" << setw(10) << "c" << setw(10)
            << "d" << setw(20) << "TaxiCab" << '\n';
  std::cout << "\n"; // Needless to say you can ignore cout<<
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      for (int a = i + 2; a < n; a++) {
        for (int b = a; b < n; b++) {
          x = std::pow(i, 3) + std::pow(j, 3);
          y = std::pow(a, 3) + std::pow(b, 3);
          if (x == y && i != j && i != b && i != a && j != a && j != b &&
              a != b) {
            std::cout << setw(10) << i << setw(10) << j << setw(10) << a
                      << setw(10) << b << setw(20) << x << '\n';
            count = count + 1;
            if (count > 15) {
              return 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int main() {
  clock_t begin = clock();
  ramanujan(50);
  std::cout << "Done!\n";
  clock_t end = clock();
  double timeSec = (end - begin) / static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  std::cout << timeSec << " Seconds taken";
}
```

Python version

```
import time
from numba import njit


@njit  # Comment this line if there is a Numba error
def ramanujan(n):
    count = 0
    print("a   b    c    d    TaxiCab")
    for x in range(1, n):
        for y in range(x, n):
            for a in range(x, n):
                for b in range(a, n):  # Python for loops

                    z = (x ** 3) + (y ** 3)
                    z2 = (a ** 3) + (b ** 3)

                    if (
                        z == z2
                        and x != y
                        and x != a
                        and x != b
                        and y != a
                        and y != b
                        and a != b
                    ):
                        print(x, y, a, b, z)
                        count = count + 1
                        if count > 15:
                            return  # Breaks all for loops once 10 such pairs are found


# Dont worry about the problem setup

start = time.time()
ramanujan(50)
print("Done")
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: did you use a debugger? Would be easier to compare the two if you had used same variable names

Comment: Ignoring numerous elephants in the room, I'll just say this: it's obviously not the same code. In C++ the first two levels of your for loops iterate over [1;n) and [j+1;n). in python they iterate over [1,n) and [x;n) - assuming x maps to i, and y maps to j going from python to C++, it's obvious the second for loop starts at different indexes. There's more instances of this happening elsewhere. Just read your code more carefully and fix it until it is actually the same between the languages.

Comment: Aside: Why do you define `i`, `x` and `y` at the top of your function, rather than the scope they are used in?

Comment: You can speed up the C++ program by replacing `pow(x,3)` with `x * x * x`.  Minimally, this removes function call and return overhead.

Comment: I may be wrong, but format apart, the outputs look the same to me: [Python](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jk5NY0QKWuRj2wt4), [C++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IxyEkncfzrTQzNgx)

Comment: This is very strange because on my system it as attached, do you see the problem. I compiled using GCC (G++ from MinGW) and I am using Anaconda python distro. if this matters. https://imgur.com/a/KnWPc20

Comment: Have you tried Thomas Matthews' hint? `std::pow` returns a floating point value, so there can be some rounding errors.

Comment: That was it.... Thanks, it was due to rounding errors introduced by std::pow(x,n) function. I should have known that it would return a floating number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `std::pow` to evaluate the power of integers is prone to rounding errors, due to the limited precision of floating point numbers.

A better (and probably faster) approach, if the exact value is needed and there is no risk of overflowing the range of integer values, is to use simple multiplications.

The following is also a slightly improved (IMHO) algorithm for solving OP's problem, if I understood it correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

int ramanujan(int n)
{    
    using std::setw;
    // Evaluate all the possible pairs and collect the sums
    std::map<long, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> sums;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            auto sum =  long(i) * i * i + long(j) * j * j;
            auto it = sums.find(sum);
            if ( it != sums.end() )
                it->second.emplace_back(i, j);
            else
                sums.emplace(sum, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>{{i, j}});
        }
    }

    // Now print only the sums of powers (sorted) that
    // are generated by more then one couple
    int count = 0;
    std::cout << setw(8) << "a" << setw(8) << "b"
              << setw(8) << "c" << setw(8) << "d" << setw(16) << "TaxiCab" << '\n'
              << "------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (auto const & i : sums)
    {
        if ( i.second.size() > 1 )
        {
            ++count;
            std::cout << setw(8) << i.second[0].first     // a
                      << setw(8) << i.second[0].second    // b
                      << setw(8) << i.second[1].first     // c
                      << setw(8) << i.second[1].second    // d
                      << setw(16) << i.first << '\n';     // a^3 + b^3 (= c^3 + d^3)
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Which, if 50 is passed, would output

```
       a       b       c       d         TaxiCab
------------------------------------------------------
       1      12       9      10            1729
       2      16       9      15            4104
       2      24      18      20           13832
      10      27      19      24           20683
       4      32      18      30           32832
       2      34      15      33           39312
       9      34      16      33           40033
       3      36      27      30           46683
      17      39      26      36           64232
      12      40      31      33           65728
       4      48      36      40          110656
       6      48      27      45          110808
Done!
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. The c and d values are not correct (as written in your answer, I am yet to run it). a^3 + b^3 should be = c^3 + d^3. Interestingly the TaxiCab numbers are right. [Wikipedia article on problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number))

Comment: @SamirChauhan Thanks, good catch! I had mistakenly copy pasted a `.first` instead of `.second`, so that it printed the same value (c) two times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the rounding errors introduced by the std::pow(x,n) function. It returns a float number and causes rounding errors. Replacing it pow(i,3) with long(i)*i*i solved the issue.

Can anyone comment why such rounding error was not a problem for Python?

Comment: different `pow` implementations will have different rounding errors, you shouldn't expect exact results when floating point numbers are involved

Comment: In standard C-Python integer**integer should be exact (unlimited integer precision) https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/pow The Numba version is differnt, since it uses limited integer precision (but also in this case there should be no floats involved) BTW: If you don't wan't to measure compiletime+runtime in your Numba function, run it once before timing...